# ¿Cómo acceder a los elementos de un array de JavaScript en un controlador Java?

Tags: javascript, java

Estoy intentando recorrer un array el cual rescato desde JavaScript a un controlador Java y acceder a sus elementos, la estructura al imprimir dicho array cuenta con esta estructura al utilizar este código:

```
[{"Ingresos":"","Febrero":"","Marzo":""},{"Ingresos":"a","Febrero":"f1","Marzo":"m1"},{"Ingresos":"b","Febrero":"f2","Marzo":"m2"}]

String array[] = request.getParameterValues("datos");
       
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {

   System.out.println(array[i]);    
}
```

La idea es hacer un insert con los datos del array, pero no logro conseguir separar cada elemento para hacerlo. Un ejemplo sería que quedase algo como esto:

```
new DAO_Accion().insert(a, f1, m1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Me gustaría ayudarte, pero no estoy segura de entender el problema, si la estructura en js es como la que describes, no se trata de un array de strings, sino un array de objetos con esos tres atributos.

No se si el problema es que te viene en un objeto JSON sin deserializar, en ese caso, tendría en cuenta si esos 3 atributos son dinámicos o estáticos

Si se trata de atributos estáticos, crearía una clase con esos 3 atributos (y sus getters y setters) y lo deserializaria)

```
public class MyObject {
    private String ingresos;
    private String febrero;
    private String marzo;

    public MyObject() {
    }

    public String getIngresos() {
        return ingresos;
    }

    public void setIngresos(String ingresos) {
        this.ingresos = ingresos;
    }

    public String getFebrero() {
        return febrero;
    }

    public void setFebrero(String febrero) {
        this.febrero = febrero;
    }

    public String getMarzo() {
        return marzo;
    }

    public void setMarzo(String marzo) {
        this.marzo = marzo;
    }
}
```

Para deserializarlo

```
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
List<MyObject> objetos = objectMapper.readValue(stringConLosDatos, new TypeReference<List<MyObject>>(){});
```

Esta lista ya se podría recorrer sin problema con el foreach.

Por otro lado, si se trata de atributos dinámicos y no son siempre los mismos, lo deserializaria como una Lista de HasMaps

```
TypeReference<List<HashMap<String, String>>> typeRef 
  = new TypeReference<List<HashMap<String, String>>>() {};
List<HashMap<String, String>> lista = mapper.readValue(jsonInput, typeRef);
```

Esta lista se puede recorrer con un foreach y para acceder a sus valores podemos utilizar la función **values()**